# SwiftUI: How to update published property of one class (ObservableObject) with published property of a location manager class?

Tags: swiftui, property-wrapper

I want to update the Published property of my ChallengeManager class with data passed in from LocationManager.
Here is the simplified code with the relevant bits:

**LocationManager**

```
final class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var challengeManager = ChallengeManager()
    ...
    //a func called from locationManager delegate converts the region to an instance of an Area object then calls a method on the ChallengeManager class like this:
    
    challengeManager.loadChallenge(for: activeArea)
...
```

**ChallengeManager**

```
final class ChallengeManager: ObservableObject {
   @Published var isShowingChallenge = false
   @Published var challengeToDisplay: Challenge?

func loadChallenge(for area: Area) {
   if let challenge = area.challenge { //gets challenge property of area object
      self.challengeToDisplay = challenge
      self.isShowingChallenge = true
   }
}
```

**Finally, the ContentView:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @ObservedObject var challengeManager = ChallengeManager()
...
```

*(To be honest, I can get the results I want by adding an ObservedObject for the LocationManager in the View and then passing the values into a func there. But I don't like the idea of doing this for multiple views. And I also want loadChallenge() to do more heavy lifting. It seems to me that it should be the single source of truth. No?)*

**The problem:**

If I try to access challengeManager.challengeToDisplay inside the ContentView, the value is always nil.
Print statements in the loadChallenge() func tell me that the value from the locationManager is being received correctly. But @Published var challengeToDisplay is not changing.
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`challengeManager` in `LocationManager` and `challengeManager` in `ContentView` are two different instances. They are not related. You have to use the same instance.

The convention is

- `@StateObject` creates an object and owns it

  ```
  @StateObject var challengeManager = ChallengeManager()
  ```
- `@ObservedObject` does not create and own the object, it will be passed thru the view hierarchy.

  ```
  @ObservedObject var challengeManager : ChallengeManager
  ```

You can also use `@EnvironmentObject` somewhere at the beginning of the view hierarchy.

Side note:

`SwiftUI` relies on non-optionals much more than Swift. For the published challenge this enum with associated types if more SwiftUI-like

```
enum ChallengeState {
    case idle, display(Challenge)
}
```

and

```
final class ChallengeManager: ObservableObject {
   @Published var challengeState : ChallengeState = .idle

func loadChallenge(for area: Area) {
   if let challenge = area.challenge { //gets challenge property of area object
      challengeState = .display(challenge)
   } else {
      challengeState = .idle
   }
}
```

In the view `switch` on the state.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried your suggestions, but things are still not working. As you correctly pointed out, the challengeManager in the two classes is not the same. So now I think the problem is with the way that I create challengeManager and call its methods inside the LocationManager class. Is there a simple way to pass the same instance into LocationManager?

Comment: If the challenge depends on the location retrieve the location inside of `ChallengeManager` not the other way round

Answer (score 0):

```
@ObservedObject var challengeManager = ChallengeManager()
```

This is creating a new instance of `ChallengeManager`, which won't be the one you're dealing with inside `LocationManager`.

You should be passing in the challenge manager when instantiating `ContentView`, not giving the property a default value.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but as I mention in my comment to @vadian (who made a similar observation), it didn't quite do the trick.